# react native project shows "MaxListenersExceededWarning" warning when i :npm install" it

Tags: node.js, react-native, node-modules, npm-install

I am having this error again and again while trying to do "npm install" in my react native project. it also turn off my wifi router for a while.

here is full error in terminal. I tried to look for solutions online but could not fine done.
my node version
20.7.0
my npm version
10.1.0

```
(node:10092) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin 
is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-async-generator-functions instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is 
no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-catch-binding instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread instead.
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'D:\\rise-ai\\node_modules\\react-native',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'D:\rise-ai\node_modules\react-native\ReactCommon\react\renderer\textlayoutmanager'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'D:\\rise-ai\\node_modules\\react-native\\ReactCommon\\react\\renderer\\textlayoutmanager'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'D:\\rise-ai\\node_modules\\@react-native',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'D:\rise-ai\node_modules\@react-native\gradle-plugin\src'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'D:\\rise-ai\\node_modules\\@react-native\\gradle-plugin\\src'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles/-/ansi-styles-4.3.0.tgz failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was happening due to slow internet. problem solved when internet was fast enough